# Step into/over implementation when develop own debugger

Tags: windows, debugging

I'm developing my own (windows) debugger.
I implemented breakpoint and etc already. but I want to add new implementation to step into/over.

I know that there is no any debug api for that. How can I implement step over/into?

I know step over/into is just implemented by `exception code(0xCC, INT 3)` which is in the `next opcode`. but If then, Is there no problem on Multi-thread program? I think my debugger will be in confusion when two threads are running for same function.

Comment: Implement StepOver by setting a breakpoint on the next line of code.  Implement StepInto by setting the processor's TF flag.  Which generates a break for every single instruction.  Keep stepping until it lands at a source code line.  PDB and DbgHelp api required to know the mapping between source code lines and addresses.  This has been done many times btw, use Google to avoid reinventing that wheel.